# Code First Complex Type Or Foreign Key Relationship?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm writing an MVC5 application with EF6 which allows users to enter job timesheets, job notes and email the customer an update.

I want my database structure to compose of 3 tables for this (Timers, JobNotes and Emails). I can have 3 models like this;

```
[Table("Timers")]
public partial class TimerModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    ...etc

    public virtual CustomerEmailModel CustomerEmail { get; set; }
}

[Table("JobNotes")]
public partial class JobNoteModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Column("Username")]
    public string User { get; set; }
    ...etc

    public virtual CustomerEmailModel CustomerEmail { get; set; }
}

[ComplexType]
public partial class CustomerEmailModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Email Customer?")]
    public bool SendEmail { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string To { get; set; }

    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

But this obviously doens't create the Email table, and instead adds the properties to the Timer and JobNotes tables (e.g. Email_SendEmail, Email_To, etc).

If i remove the [ComplexType] annotation, and change my other models to have;

```
    public int? EmailID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EmailID")]
    public virtual CustomerEmailModel CustomerEmail { get; set; }
```

Then it does create the table, but then i'm unsure of how to add new entries (i.e. emails are added on the fly, with a 0..1 relationship. It would mean that i would need to add to the email explicitly, get the added entries ID, and then assign it to the other model (timer or jobnote model) EmailID.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks for any help in advance. Please let me know if you need any further information.

EDIT:
It seems that I do need to provide more information from the answers I'm getting so far.
I have two databases in play. A vendor supplied database, for an application which records job, timesheet, employee, customer, etc information. Lets call it DB01.
And a database (call it DB02) for my application (its a mobile app for users to record timesheet or jobnote information, and submit it to DB01).

The mobile app has a user interface which has the following key inputs;
Start Time, Stop Time, Break Time, Job Selector (drop down), Timesheet Title, Timesheet Notes, Send Email To Customer (checkbox), To Address, Subject, Body.

As such, a complex type does work correctly (and is what i'm using in the interm). However, because I have another page which will be able to email the customer as well, I wanted a separate email table (however, i don't want to have to save the email separately, and then assign it to the timesheet or jobnote).

Also - the only tables i need (for DB02), are the ones to store the timesheet, jobnote and email data. Once the timesheet or jobnote gets submitted, it can be deleted or archived. I only need these tables, because all other relevant information is contained in DB01. I can retrieve this data from views on DB02, and i can submit the information from DB02 to DB01 with a stored procedure from DB02. (DB02 has DB01 as a linked server)

Comment: Complex Type doesn't create separate table, but creates additional columns in table of entity that uses it. EF maps this columns to property of Complex Type. You can read [this](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/04/01/making-complex-types-useful.aspx). If you want a separate table use foreign keys.

Comment: I've already stated this in the original question.. what i was after is a hybrid of functionality. i.e. foreign keys give me the email table that i was after. complex type gives me the data-binding i'm after.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example of the use of foreign keys with EF6

```
 public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual B Bobject { get; set; }
    public int BId;
    public virtual ICollection<C> Cs { get; set; }
}
 public class B
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<A> As { get; set; }
    }
}
 public class C
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string TransactionId { get; set; }
        public virtual A Aobj { get; set; }
        public int AId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: As stated, I already know how to create the foreign key relationship. What i wasnt sure of, is how i go about adding a new entity on the fly. e.g. each Timer can have 0 or 1 emails (i.e. a user doesnt have to send an email, but can if they want to). With a foreign key relationship however, i need to explicitly save an email to the context, then assign the newly added email's id to the timer's emailid, and then save the timer. it's a 2-phase process, whereas i just want to be able to say save timer.

Answer (score 0):

You have quite big issues with your database to begin with, and you're not clearly defining the different sets of data.

I've redeveloped what you're trying to achieve using the Fluent API.

```
public class TimeSheet
{
    public TimeSheet()
    {
        this.TimeSheetId = Guid.NewGuid()
                               .ToString();
    }

    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Job Job { get; set; }
    public string JobId { get; set; }
    public string TimeSheetId { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public Employee()
    {
        this.EmployeeId = Guid.NewGuid()
                              .ToString();
    }

    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TimeSheet> TimeSheets { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Mail> MailsSent { get; set; }
}

public class Job
{
    public Job()
    {
        this.JobId = Guid.NewGuid()
                         .ToString();
    }

    // One job will have one client
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public string JobId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    // A Job may have many time sheets
    public virtual ICollection<TimeSheet> TimeSheets { get; set; }
}

public class Client
{
    public Client()
    {
        this.ClientId = Guid.NewGuid()
                            .ToString();
    }

    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    // A client can have many work packages / jobs.
    public virtual ICollection<Job> WorkPackages { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Mail> Mails { get; set; }
}

public class Mail
{
    public Mail()
    {
        this.MailId = Guid.NewGuid()
                          .ToString();
    }

    // A mail item will reference one client.
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public string MailId { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }

    // A mail item will also originate from an employee
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }

    // This doesn't belong here... as if it isn't 
    // being sent, then it wouldn't make sense to create 
    // create the email in the first place...
    // If you want to queue emails, rename the field to `IsSent`
    // 
    // public bool SendEmail { get; set; }
}

public class TimeSheetConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<TimeSheet>
{
    public TimeSheetConfiguration()
    {
        this.ToTable("TimeSheets");

        this.HasKey(timeSheet => timeSheet.TimeSheetId);
        this.Property(property => property.TimeSheetId).IsRequired().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
        this.Property(property => property.JobId)      .IsRequired();
        this.Property(property => property.EmployeeId) .IsRequired();

        this.HasRequired(timeSheet => timeSheet.Job)     .WithMany(job => job.TimeSheets).HasForeignKey(timeSheet => timeSheet.JobId);
        this.HasRequired(timeSheet => timeSheet.Employee).WithMany(emp => emp.TimeSheets).HasForeignKey(timeSheet => timeSheet.EmployeeId);
    }
}

public class EmployeeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeConfiguration()
    {
        this.ToTable("Employees");

        this.HasKey(emp => emp.EmployeeId);
        this.Property(property => property.EmployeeId)  .IsRequired().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
        this.Property(property => property.FirstName)   .IsRequired();
        this.Property(property => property.LastName)    .IsOptional();
        this.Property(property => property.EmailAddress).IsRequired();

        this.HasMany(employee => employee.TimeSheets).WithRequired(time => time.Employee).HasForeignKey(time => time.EmployeeId);
        this.HasMany(employee => employee.MailsSent) .WithRequired(mail => mail.Employee).HasForeignKey(mail => mail.EmployeeId);
    }
}

public class ClientConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Client>
{
    public ClientConfiguration()
    {
        this.ToTable("Clients");

        this.HasKey(client => client.ClientId);
        this.Property(property => property.ClientId)    .IsRequired().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
        this.Property(property => property.EmailAddress).IsRequired();

        this.HasMany(property => property.WorkPackages).WithRequired(job  => job.Client) .HasForeignKey(job  => job.ClientId);
        this.HasMany(property => property.Mails)       .WithRequired(mail => mail.Client).HasForeignKey(mail => mail.ClientId);
    }
}

public class JobConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Job>
{
    public JobConfiguration()
    {
        this.ToTable("Jobs");

        this.HasKey(job => job.JobId);
        this.Property(property => property.JobId)   .IsRequired().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
        this.Property(property => property.Name)    .IsRequired();
        this.Property(property => property.ClientId).IsRequired();
        this.Property(property => property.Notes)   .IsRequired();

        this.HasMany(job => job.TimeSheets).WithRequired(time => time.Job)             .HasForeignKey(time => time.JobId);
        this.HasRequired(job => job.Client).WithMany    (client => client.WorkPackages).HasForeignKey(job => job.ClientId);
    }
}

public class MailConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Mail>
{
    public MailConfiguration()
    {
        this.ToTable("Mails");

        this.HasKey(mail => mail.MailId);
        this.Property(property => property.MailId)    .IsRequired().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
        this.Property(property => property.ClientId)  .IsRequired();
        this.Property(property => property.EmployeeId).IsRequired();
        this.Property(property => property.Subject)   .IsRequired();
        this.Property(property => property.Body)      .IsRequired();

        this.HasRequired(mail => mail.Client)  .WithMany(client => client.Mails)        .HasForeignKey(mail => mail.ClientId);
        this.HasRequired(mail => mail.Employee).WithMany(employee => employee.MailsSent).HasForeignKey(mail => mail.EmployeeId); 
    }
}

public class ExampleContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Mail> Mails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TimeSheet> TimeSheets { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is called when the model for a derived context has been initialized, but
    ///             before the model has been locked down and used to initialize the context.  The default
    ///             implementation of this method does nothing, but it can be overridden in a derived class
    ///             such that the model can be further configured before it is locked down.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Typically, this method is called only once when the first instance of a derived context
    ///             is created.  The model for that context is then cached and is for all further instances of
    ///             the context in the app domain.  This caching can be disabled by setting the ModelCaching
    ///             property on the given ModelBuidler, but note that this can seriously degrade performance.
    ///             More control over caching is provided through use of the DbModelBuilder and DbContextFactory
    ///             classes directly.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="modelBuilder">The builder that defines the model for the context being created. </param>
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MailConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ClientConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EmployeeConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TimeSheetConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new JobConfiguration());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see my edit of the original post. Using your code - do i still need to explicitly save an email separately from a timesheet? Sorry if i'm not explaining what i want all that well.

Comment: with my code you would of had to specify both the employee and client it has no relationships configured with the time sheets. To access the emails you would need to create a class deriving from DbContext and specify each entity in as a type parameter in each DbSet<TEntity> property. I'm on mobile so can't pump out an example but look at the class directly above, copy it to suit your need.  After that update the db by doing these steps. `CTRL + Q` > type and select Package Manager Console > type: Enable-Migrations (hit tab for autocompletion) > add-migration FirstConfig> Type : update-database